# What body modifications or body adaptations would be needed to be able to make human can sit longer or indefinitelly without affecting their health?

Tags: science-based, biology, humans, xenobiology, anatomy

my question is in the title, i want to know what kind of body modifications or body adaptations needed or look like for human to be able to sit in prolonged time without affecting their health. Since as far as i know human body is not effective in sitting in a prolonged times or stay still in prolonged times which is unhealthy to them and can affect human posture.

This excluding any tools adaptations, i want to know the body adaptations, and yeah i know there exist some chair design that try to thwart this problem, or maybe in the future portable pc or phone maybe strong enough or has enough feature for ppl to work while doing active activity rather than today common desk job, so who know would such body modification would become a reality or not, beside human are generally lazy after all.

And to be clear, i mean sitting in general not really stay/stand still, which also include other sitting posture if possible, excluding traditional japanese formal sitting, which i dont think it should be considered sitting posture to me, since it feel more like a kneel/kowtow/prostrate, which more affecting the knee rather than the rear, but feel free to correct me or add it too if want to, it not hurt to know. but just the common sitting in chair is acceptable too.

And if possible they still can walk or do activity if want to, even with that modification, just in case ppl will suggest something like merge them with sitting chair or change the human posture to permanently in sitting position or posture and only can sit while the chair bot do all the activity for them.

here a gif from cyanide and happines....just because.

[image]

feel free to correct my grammar or put appropriate tag to my question.

Comment: Long term sitting has three problems: muscle atrophy, pressure sores, and the [flesh bonding with the fabric](https://www.nydailynews.com/news/national/obese-man-cut-chair-stuck-2-years-dies-skin-fused-maggot-infested-fabric-article-1.119328). I'm sure that it would also cause spinal problems, but they didn't come up in a quick search. (BTW, note from that article that the man sat in his own waste for 2 years. How long can you sit down before you must stand up to relieve yourself?)

Comment: with that "excluding any tools adaptations" soft skin will always be a problem, so hard shell then or similar solutions

Comment: Can conform the Japanese formal sitting and even cross legged sitting are really tough on the knees. 
Cross legged right after standing up the pressure and feeling in the knees are too painful and intense, kinda pleasurable in painful sort of way.
And my legs require some movement before I can walk normally.
Japanese is also hell if you are a bit overweight or more. All that weight on the legs and the joins really suffer. I can do it but not pleasant at all after a while.
Life tip. please change your posture guys and stand up and move after a while sitting.

Answer (score 2):

The Gelada monkeys buttocks come to mind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelada. As they spend most of their time on their bum picking at the grass and shuffling along they have developed a padded buttocks that looks quite similar to digitgrade paw.

I would add a picture but nobody needs to be startled by that. Although the reasons I remembered them was not just for their strange buttocks but their strange social dynamic where if the male does not groom the female enough they will chase him out and find a new male but that is not relevant to the question lol.

I dont think a padded buttocks and a suitable leg and spine posture is enough as there will be other issues to being seated for long periods of time but it is a start.

Comment: Gamers, write that down, write that down.